# Drawing on a headless server in Java

Tags: png, processing, headless

In java, using the Processing API, we are drawing and rendering to png.  We do not need to actually draw a window.  The question is whether there is any way of drawing to an image buffer directly.

Processing directly supports writing to pdf,  but png is not listed
    size(600,600,PDF);

processing also supports opengl renderer. In OpenGL, I have seen code to render to a buffer, though never seen that in Processing anywhere.  Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just draw to an instance of PGraphics.

Specifically, just add the Processing jar to your classpath, then you can use the PGraphics class from your Java server code to create an image and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: The processing API has much nicer drawing commands than regular java.  The question is how to direct the API to draw to an image.  PImage by itself has absolutely no drawing API.  how are you proposing to draw, setting the pixels one by one?

Comment: @Dov Processing is also a Java library, and that's how you're going to have to use it if you want to use it on a server. You would use the PGraphics class, not the PImage class.